# Dependent Variable Loop C#

Tags: c#, loops

I'd like to ask a question about how to deal with dependent variables.

```
C1=MA(X,10)
C2=MA(C1,10)
C3=C2.Minus(C1)
C4=MA(C3,10)
Final=C4.Minus(C3)
```

An illustration:Final=C4.Minus(C3), I save its two parameters C4,C3.

```
  C4(MA ok and firstTime in MA)--> C3(MA NotOK,not fstTime)---> C2(MA ok)--->C1(MA ok)
                       0------------------->  10-------------->  10+10---->10+10+10=30
```

I created a class at first to get all the informtion of each line

```
    public class IndicatorInform
    {
        char[] parenthesis = new []{'(',')'};
        char[] equal = new char[] { '=' };
        char[] comma = new char[] { ';' };
        char[] all = new char [] { '.','<'};


        string text=null;
        string funcname=null;
        string[] args=null;

        public void IndicatorInform (string expression, out string text,out string funcName,out string [] args)
        {
           string [] parts= expression.Split(equal);
           text = parts[0];
           if( parts[1].Contains(";"))
           {
               string[] subparts = parts[1].Split(parenthesis);
               funcname = subparts[0];
               args = subparts[1].Split(comma);
               if(args.Count.equal(2))
               {
                   funcarg = args[0];
                   period = Convert.ToDouble(args[1]);
               }
           }
           else
           {
               if (parts[1].Contains("Plus"))
                   funcname = "Plus";
               if (parts[1].Contains("Minus"))
                   funcname = "Minus";
               if (parts[1].Contains("Multi"))
                   funcname = "Multi";
               if (parts[1].Contains("Div"))
                   funcname = "Div";
               parts[1] = parts[1].Replace(funcname, "");
               args=parts[1].Split(all);
           }
        }
        public double Shifts {get; set;}
        public double period { get; set; }
        public string Funcname { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string funcarg { get; set; }
    }
```

And then I created a Dictonary and begin to deal with dependant variables

```
   Dictionary<string,SubIndicator> Dico=new Dictionary<string,SubIndicator> ;
        foreach (var line in richTextBox1.Lines)
        {
            SubIndicator SubInc = new SubIndicator();
            Dico.Add(SubInc.text,SubInc);
        }
        int incre=0;
        double tempvalue=0;
        foreach( string element in Dico.Keys)
        {
            string[] tempo=null;
            if(Dico[element].text.Contains("Final"))
            {
                tempo=Dico[element].args;
            }
            else
            {
                if(tempo.Contains(Dico[element].text))
                {
                    if(Dico[element].Funcname.Contains("MA") )
                    {
                        if (incre.Equals(0))
                        {tempvalue=Dico[element].period;
                        incre++;}
                        else
                        {
                            Dico[element].Shifts=tempvalue+Dico[element].period;
                            tempvalue =Dico[element].Shifts;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Dico[element].Shifts=tempvalue;
                    }
                }
            }
```

My algorithm works for the case above.But how to deal a more complicated case such as

```
  C1=MA(X,10) 
  C2=MA(X,20)
  C3=MA(C1,5)
  C4=MA(C2,10) 
  C5=MA(C3,15)
  C6=MA(C4,10)
  Final=C6.Minus(C5)
 C6(fst Time)---->C4--->C2         C5(fst Time)--->C3--> C1
            0-->10+10-->10+10+20              0--> 15+5-->15+5+10
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see what is the difference between first and second examples.  Ca you explain further.  Usually these type problems require a recursive algorithm to handle more complicated inputs.

Comment: @ jdweng  The first case each line depends on previous line 'C4--> C3---> C2--->C1'  and not the second. My algorithm is not smart enough,it only can treat line by line.

Comment: You're right. A recursive algorithm is a better solution,could you explain further? Thanks

Comment: Algorithm must start with a root (the line with final)  Then call recursive function with root as parameter.  The recursive function gets value of each element like C6 & C5.  Then call the recursive function again to get value of each element with the parameter of the recursive function being either C6 or C5 instead of root.

Comment: @ jeweng I agree with your idea. But I meet a technical problem. My algo only can deal with a simple case if you look at my code.But It can't call the recursive function again and again. Could you tell me a little bit how to write this recursive function if you have free time?

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to write a longer answer.  Math functions need to have a binary tree with element/nodes which is a class that contains a left node, right node, value, and math operator.  The element is usually a class object and can be the value in a dictionary.  Leafs nodes will contain the values while non leafs nodes will have operators with either a left node, a right node, or both a left and right node.

Math function are associated so any function can divided into a left and right component like a = b + (c + d + e + f).  b is the left component and (c + d + e + f) is the right component.  The right component can further by separated into a left and right.

You code need two pieces.  The first is to parse the input into elements.  The second part is to calculate the results.  The recursive function will perform the calculations.  The recursive checks to see if an element contains a left, and or right nodes and keeps calling the recursive function until a leaf is found that contains a value.  Then moves back up the stack of function calls replacing the math operators with value returned from left and right components.

Comment: Right now I have a class IndicatorInform that contains all the information such as a left node, right node, value, and math operator. And a dictionary contains all indicators. I tried a recursive function.But it can't do the work as you mentioned  above because this function doesn't perform well for a complicated case.

Comment: How to keep calling the recursive function until a leaf is found that contains a value. Then moves back up the stack of function calls replacing the math operators with value returned from left and right components. That's the part I dont know.

Comment: @BlancoDDP I just found this after writing up my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806814/recursive-algorithm-to-handle-depend-variables/32810622#32810622. If you take a look at my answer, it's pretty much the same thing as what jdweng has said, best way to approach this is to construct a tree and solve the tree. Take a quick look and see how an expression is approached and solved using a tree, and you'll understand jdweng's explanation.