# Recursive algorithm to handle depend variables

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I'd like to ask a question about how to deal with dependent variables by recursive algorithm.

```
C1=MA(X,10)
C2=MA(C1,10)
C3=C2.Minus(C1)
C4=MA(C3,10)
Final=C4.Minus(C3)
//Dependence:C4--> C3---> C2--->C1
```

In this example, I begin with last line. My recursive algo is to read line by line to find whether its dependent variables is in previous line.

But if I have a more complicated case

```
C1=MA(X,10) 
C2=MA(X,20)
C3=MA(C1,5)
C4=MA(C2,10) 
C5=MA(C3,15)
C6=MA(C4,10)
Final=C6.Minus(C5)
//Dependence: C6---->C4--->C2         C5--->C3--> C1
```

Reading each line to find its dependent variables doesn't work.My question is if there is a better way to find its dependent variables?

If you have some ideas that can share with me, thanks a lot.
PS.Detailed code is here [Dependent Variable Loop C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802966/dependent-variable-loop-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment53443702_32802966).

Comment: the question is really unclear - are those lines strings in some domain language? If so where is your internal representation and your code to find dependencies? In other words what have you tried?

Comment: @Carsten  If you want to see the details about my code, here is the site:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802966/dependent-variable-loop-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment53443702_32802966.

Comment: Because my previous question is too long, that's the reason why I summarize a little bit my problematic.

Comment: you should not ask the same questions more than once please

Comment: I know. I ask one more time because my previous question is too long, and  I'm afraid others don't have a clear idea. do you have any idea to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would personally implement a solution to this problem from the top of my head.

It will be about constructing an "Operation tree" which contains a recursive method `Solve()` that you can call.

I have wrote it to use an interface to be used for either hard values or "reference" to another expression.

This assumes all operations only have 2 inputs.

```
public interface IExpression {
    public int Solve();
}

// class that will contain an integer number value
public class ValueExpression : IExpression {
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public ValueExpression(int value) {
        Value = value;
    }
    public int Solve() {
        return Value;
    }
}


// class that will contain definition for expressions
public class OperationExpression : IExpression {
    public IExpression Left { get; set; }
    public IExpression Right { get; set; }
    public Operations Operation { get; set; }
    public OperationExpression() { }
    public OperationExpression(IExpression left, IExpression right, Operations operation) {
        Left = left;
        Right = right;
        Operation = operation;
    }
    public enum Operations {
        MA,
        Minus,
        Add
        // other
    }
    public int Solve() {
        switch (Operation) {
            case MA :
                // You will have to implement MA method
                return MA(left.Solve(), right.Solve());
            case Minus :
                return left.Solve().Minus(right.Solve());
            case Add :
                return left.Solve().Add(right.Solve());
        }
    }
}
```

Now you just need to find a way to get your input expressions into above format, which will end up looking like a tree. Once you call `Solve()` on your root, it will return the answer.

You can also note that the leaves will end up being the numeric values while branches will be the operations.

Of course the challenge is now:

1. Creating a way to get your input in the IExpression tree format
2. Error handling (what will you do if an expression cannot be
   resolved? Dividing by 0, exceeding max integer value, if left/right
   is null, etc)

Here is how I would setup your "complicated case" example with the above:

```
int X = 0; // Your parameter I guess?
OperationExpression C1 = new OperationExpression(new ValueExpression(X),
    new ValueExpression(10), OperationExpression.Operations.MA);

OperationExpression C2 = new OperationExpression(new ValueExpression(X),
    new ValueExpression(20), OperationExpression.Operations.MA);

OperationExpression C3 = new OperationExpression(C1,
    new ValueExpression(5), OperationExpression.Operations.MA);

OperationExpression C4 = new OperationExpression(C2,
    new ValueExpression(10), OperationExpression.Operations.MA);

OperationExpression C5 = new OperationExpression(C3,
    new ValueExpression(15), OperationExpression.Operations.MA);

OperationExpression C6 = new OperationExpression(C4
    new ValueExpression(10), OperationExpression.Operations.MA);

OperationExpression Final = new OperationExpression(C6,
    C5, OperationExpression.Operations.Minus);

var C1Result = C1.Solve();
var C2Result = C2.Solve();
var C3Result = C3.Solve();
// etc
```

Comment: @ JTY May I ask you one more question? when I copied your code and ran a test. The switch case in the solve has a problem, C# said 'the name MA doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: @Blanco DDP That's because there is no method called MA, it's your method, hence I have added a comment above it saying you will need to implement it.

Comment: thank you. Basing on my understanding of your idea, for var C3Result = C3.Solve(); the result will be X.Right?

Comment: The result of C3.Solve() will be MA(MA(X, 10), 5). I hope you do understand how it is working, because from your original question, you have not mentioned what is `X` and what is `MA(param 1, param2)`. So you will need to change some code around.